# Почему во время работы приложения кнопки исчезают?

Tags: delphi

Уважаемые программисты, может мне кто-нибудь ответить: почему во время работы приложения кнопки исчезают, а появляются лишь при наведении курсора мыши на их предполагаемое расположение?

Comment: В новом пустом приложении с формой и кнопками тоже такое происходит? Если нет, то проблема в коде.

Comment: думаю, проблема в коде. Может там ручная прорисовка формы. или тяжелые операции в главном потоке.

Comment: Может ТС поделится кодом? :)

Comment: 1. в пустом приложении такого нет, но и в моем такое происходит через раз.
2. форму прорисовываю не сам
3. код выложить весь не могу - модулей много

Comment: @АлександрЪ Попробуйте локализовать проблему удаляя/комментируя код по частям. Форма, на которой исчезают кнопки, большая? Проверяли код на утечки памяти?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Форма большая (много компонентов), не так давно программирую, можете описать как проверять программу на утечки памяти?

Comment: @АлександрЪ используйте [FastMM][1].
Вот [здесь][2] есть статья по поводу ловли утечек и про FastMM в частности.


  [1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/
  [2]: http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2009/05/blog-post_24.html

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Большое Вам спасибо!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю это проблемы совместимости delphi 7 и windows 7/vista.

Comment: У Delphi-7 нет таких проблем.

Comment: у Delphi-7, как и у других версий делфи есть такая проблема. Если проект скомпилирован под XP, то есть вероятность того, что VCL на 7/Vista будет работать не так, как задумывалось.

Comment: @teanЫЧ Можете пример показать?

Comment: пример был в проекте, которым я занимался на предыдущей работе. Код скинуть не могу, ибо копирайт ^^. Но приходилось компилировать проект под XP и под 7 отдельно. Ибо некоторые визуальные компоненты либо были не видны, либо тупо заливались черным цветом. Причем никаких выкрутасов в коде не было. вот.

Comment: Сторонние компоненты? И в чем была разница в коде между XP и 7? Покажите мне пустой проект, в котором кнопка не видна или заливается черным цветом.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, скажите, а возможно снизить такую вероятность? Или вовсе исключить?

Comment: В общем скорее всего проблема в XPManifest, решений два: либо не использовать его, либо ставить заплатку http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=37403

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поиграться со свойствами DoubleBuffered и ParentDoubleBuffered, а также Transparent. Частенько проблема именно в этом.